# JavaScript promises and if/else statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, promise, q

When I use `filemanager` function for directory (`/`) code works well, but when I call file (`/index.html`) code returns an error.

I see that the problem in if/else statement (`readdir` runs even if `isDir` returned `false`), but I don't know how correctly use it with promises.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    Q = require('q'),
    readdir = Q.denodeify(fs.readdir),
    readFile = Q.denodeify(fs.readFile);

function isDir(path) {
    return Q.nfcall(fs.stat, __dirname + path)
        .then(function (stats) {
            if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
}

function filemanager(path) {
    if (isDir(path)) {
        return readdir(__dirname + path)
            .then(function (files) {
                return files.map(function (file) {
                    return ...;
                });
            })
            .then(Q.all);
    } else {
        return readFile(__dirname + path, 'utf-8')
            .then(function (content) {
                return ...;
            });
    }
}

filemanager('/').done(
    function (data) {
        ...
    },
    function (err) {
        ...
    }
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isDir` returns a promise, which is always a truthy value. You will need to put the condition in the `then` callback to have access to the boolean value:

```
function isDir(path) {
    return Q.nfcall(fs.stat, __dirname + path)
        .then(function (stats) {
            return stats.isDirectory()
        });
}

function filemanager(path) {
    return isDir(path).then(function(isDir) {
        if (isDir) {
            return readdir(__dirname + path)
                .then(function (files) {
                    return files.map(function (file) {
                        return ...;
                    });
                })
                .then(Q.all);
        } else {
            return readFile(__dirname + path, 'utf-8')
                .then(function (content) {
                    return ...;
                });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `isDir(path)` evaluates to a Promise. So you cannot get the result directly from that function. Rather, you have to wait for that returned Promise to resolve, and then evaluate the value there. So, you need a construct like `isDir(path).then(...)` instead of the `if (isDir(path))` that you are currently using.